# Use extension's localStorage wrapper function in an injected script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension's content script injects a script into gmail page via `<script>` element (main.js). The injected script needs some data from the settings stored in the extension's `localStorage` by `options.js` script of the options page.

The options page script can successfully use `loadDomain()` function that reads `localStorage.domain` value. This function is defined in a common functions script `storage.js` that is also injected on gmail page via `<script>` element along with `main.js`.

**The problem** is that `loadDomain()` returns `undefined` when called in the injected `main.js` instead of the actual values stored on the options page.

manifest.json:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://mail.google.com/*", "http://*/*, https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "38": "icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "SalesUp",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
    "js/gmail.js",
    "main.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `loadDomain` is declared in options.html

Comment: In file options.html add <script src="js/options.js"></script> and in options.js declared loadDomain() ?

Comment: Does not work, he sees loadDomain() but empty array, and on page options.html array exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chat discussion showed that `loadDomain()` was invoked from the `<script>`-injected main.js.

One part of the problem was caused by the fact that Chrome isolates the web page (with its scripts, also the injected ones) from the content scripts, as well as the background page. Another part was that `localStorage` is different on each domain (actually, [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)), so whatever was stored inside the options page of the extension was not available in a content script that runs in the context of the web page and has access to its `localStorage` only, not the extension's `localStorage`.

The solution comprises two things:

1. instead of `localStorage` use `chrome.storage.sync` to store the extension settings or `chrome.storage.local` to store the temporary stuff that shouldn't be synced to Google servers.
2. use custom DOM-events to communicate between the injected script and the content script.

---

The code:

**Injected main.js:**

- sending a request (`detail` key may be used to pass some data):

  ```
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("getDomains", {detail: {something: "hello"}}));
  ```
- listening for a response:

  ```
  document.addEventListener("receiveDomains", function(e) {
      var domains = e.detail;
      console.log("Received domains", domains);
      ...............
  });
  ```

**Content script content.js:**

```
document.addEventListener("getDomains", function(e) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("domains", function(result) {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("receiveDomains", {detail: result.domains}));
    });
});
```

**Options page options.js:**

```
function save_options() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({domains: ["domain1", "domain2"]});
}
```

Comment: Make sure to update the question as well. It's not useful if required information is in the chat.